# A-Frame application keeps crashing. Render warning in console

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm building an A-Frame application that has a lot of collada models in the scene.

I think it may be crashing my application because I keep getting this error

CommandBufferContext.Offscreen-MainThread-0x7fca4c904720 RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0.

WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.

What is the best way to fix the issue?

Comment: What browser, What version?

Comment: If this is mobile, then it is because mobile browsers have an extremely small amount of RAM per browser tab before it crashes. For WebVR, it is very easy to go over that limit so current mobile browsers today are not very suitable for VR.

Comment: It was for chrome on desktop

Comment: Those error might be a red herring. There might be something else breaking or preventing the scene from loading but we'll need more information to help you. Can you provide a link to the breaking app, or code at least?